# Run the program with Docker

Tags: linux, docker, vps

I want to run the program on a VPS server Ubuntu 18.04. It must be run with Docker with this command:

```
docker run --rm --name aparser -v $(pwd)/aparser:/app -p 9091:9091 -t aparser/runtime./aparser -foreground
```

But I get an error:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

Inputting
`sudo systemctl status docker.service` 
I get:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-05-25 09:31:14 UTC; 14min ago   
      Docs: https://docs.docker.com 
   Process: 30302 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1 Main PID: 30302 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) 
May 25 09:31:12 p619677.vps systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited,code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 25 09:31:12 p619677.vps systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 25 09:31:12 p619677.vps systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
May 25 09:31:14 p619677.vps systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 25 09:31:14 p619677.vps systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 25 09:31:14 p619677.vps systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
May 25 09:31:14 p619677.vps systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 25 09:31:14 p619677.vps systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 25 09:31:14 p619677.vps systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

Comment: your docker daemon is not running. In your logs, it shows it failed to start.

Comment: did you try to run the command as sudo ?

Comment: yes, user is root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This server does not support Docker.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You will run docker daemon before run docker container. 
Run command for start docker service 
**`sudo systemctl start docker`**

After starting docker you can run with your command and sudo if you are not in sudo 
**`sudo docker run --rm --name aparser -v $(pwd)/aparser:/app -p 9091:9091 -t aparser/runtime./aparser -foreground`**

If systemctl not working for you run 
**`sudo service docker start`**